# How can I stop Unity from lagging and freezing?

Tags: unity, compiz

My Ubuntu 11.10 isn't working properly,Unity has freezes and lags when i launch a program,launch dash,workspace switcher.....etc.a friend of mine told me to decrease the shared memory (from BIOS) from 256 to 128MB,i did that and unity was working perfect with no freezes at all but 90% of boot times Unity does not load so i set shared memory back to 256MB.How can i fix that.Thank You.
Graphic card:GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a (Built in)

Comment: Changing the shared memory in the BIOS does not help, since this option is used when you are using the motherboard graphicas card. When using a GEForce card, you are using the memory in the card, not shared memory.

Comment: What driver are you using, the proprietary NVIDIA driver? If yes, what version please?